# What Java design pattern fits the scenario of adding a user to multiple systems based on csv values?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am working on a project where I need to add users to multiple systems (active directory, a database, & Sisense) based on data received from a spreadsheet. I've coded  can get the data input correctly into each system, but I am struggling to figure out how to organize my code, in terms of what design pattern to use.

I have a model class for each component that contains the field each system needs:

1. ActiveDirectoryUser
2. SisenseUser
3. DatabaseUser

Then, I have what I call the worker class for each of these that actually does creates the user in the system.

- ActiveDirectoryWorker
- SisenseWorker
- DatabaseWorker

The basic flow of my code is

1. Read in each line from the spreadsheet
2. Validate the input is valid.
3. Create a instance of each model class that contains the appropriate fields.
4. Call the individual worker classes that control how the user get added to the respective system.  The model instance will be passed into this class.

I've read up on some of the various design patterns, but none of the explanations are in "plain" English.  Still learning the ropes here a bit, so I'd appreciate someone suggesting a model that fits my scenario.

Comment: **Design Patterns are not this specific.**  Write some code that accomplishes what you want.

Comment: It totally depends on the rest of the system. Is it only doing the specified task? Than you just hard code the calls to the workers and move on to something more interesting. If, however, you have a more complex task / system at hand you could use a message bus and the CSV-reader populates a new user on this message bus. The workers then can subscribe to the message bus and add the user to their system. For this, I guess, you would need some kind of general user class, because the message bus should not know about the specific user objects. There are many other ways to implement it.

Comment: Not everything in CS is a design pattern, but you would want to attach both databases to the Model class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds as though you've defined three distinct data models, one for each storage. That makes your job more difficult than it has to be. Instead, consider modelling data based on data in the spreadsheet. You could, for instance, define a class called `SpreadsheetUser`, which contains the valid data from a spreadsheet row.

Now define an interface, e.g. `UserCreator`:

```
interface UserCreator
{
    void Create(SpreadsheetUser user);
}
```

Now loop through each row in your spreadsheet, validate the data and then call `Create` on a [Composite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern), which could be defined like this:

```
class CompositeUserCreator : UserCreator
{
    UserCreator[] creators;

    CompositeUserCreator(params UserCreator[] creators)
    {
        this.creators = creators;
    }

    public void Create(SpreadsheetUser user)
    {
        foreach (creator in creators)
            creator.Create(user);
    }
}
```

You also define three concrete implementations of `UserCreator`, one for each storage system, and create the composite like this:

```
CompositeUserCreator creator =
    new CompositeUserCreator(
        new ActiveDirectoryUserCreator(/* perhaps some config values here... */),
        new SisenseUserCreator(/* ... and here... */),
        new DatabaseUserCreator(/* ... and here... */));
```

You'll still have the problem of dealing with failures. What should happen if you've already created a user in active directory, but then Sisense creation fails? That is, however, not a problem introduced by the *Composite* pattern, but a problem which is inherent in distributed computing.

Comment: I plan to handle error handling within each component and return a pass or fail code from each create method() to determine if/how to proceed to next step.